# change numbers into the sum of their figures

Tags: r

I've got this simple question: how can I change a vector consisting of 10 numbers into a vector consisting of ten numbers which are the sum of the figures of the first numbers? So 11 in the first vector becomes 2, 234 becomes 9.

Comment: What have you already tried yourself?

Comment: what is your expectation from a number 978? you want 9+7+8=24 or further 2+4=6?

Comment: The first option is my goal, so 9+7+8 adds up to 24. But the second one would include the method for getting the first one?

Comment: Both answers work fine! Thanks! The problem behind it is from a highschool math competition in the Netherlands ("www.wiskundeolympiade.nl; under Wedstrijdarchief you can find English versions of the problems and their solutions).   The particular problem here is: find a number that ends with 26, is dividable by 26 and   its digits count up to 26. You can do this by paper (I did) but to learn R I think it is good to translate the problems into R and get the right answer. Another problem for instance is: count up al digits in the numbers from 1 to 1983, which can be solved by the answers given.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `str_extract_all` from `stringr` to get the individual numbers, convert them to `numeric` and get the `sum`.

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(c(11, 234), '\\d'), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
```

Comment: # With your help: R solution to the problem: find the first
# number that ends at 26, is dividable by 26 and whose figures count up to 26.

a1<-which((1:11111*100 + 26)%%26==0)#numbers ending at 26, modulo 26=0
a2<-a1*100+26#creates the vector of numbers ending at 26, dividable by 26, whose figures have to be
# counted to see if they count up to 26
a3<-which(sapply(str_extract_all(a2, '\\d'), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))==26)#indexes numbers whose
#figures count up to 26
a2[a3[1]]#first element that counts up to 26, extracted from a2 by index a3[1]=  36, a2[36].

Comment: @PietvanTuijl  Thanks for the background info and glad that you were able to sort it out.